# No se visualiza el portal de usuario en SquirrelMail. Puede tratarse de un problema de apache2?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, email

He instalado Postfix, Courier y Squirrelmail. Al acceder al portal de login de squirrelmail funciona correctamente, pero al hacer login, no se reproducen los php correspondientes. Adjunto imagenes:
[image: Pantalla de login]

[image: despues de logearse]